# OpenEdge - Progress ABL: How to open a web browser inside a dialog window

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, 4gl

For the moment i have a code that allow me to open a web browser directly from my Progress application.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cProgramName  AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cPageAddress  AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iReturnResult AS INTEGER    NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
    cProgramName = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
    cPageAddress    = "http://www.progress.com".

RUN WinExec (INPUT cProgramName + CHR(32) + cPageAddress , INPUT 1, OUTPUT iReturnResult).

PROCEDURE WinExec EXTERNAL "KERNEL32.DLL":
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER ProgramName AS CHARACTER.
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER VisualStyle AS LONG.
    DEFINE RETURN PARAMETER StatusCode  AS LONG.
END PROCEDURE.
```

Now i want to open the browser inside a dialogue box, pop-up window or a frame. I can't find any code to help me with that !

Comment: Please explain why the above should not work from a dialog-frame or frame? Also please ad your OpenEdge release to the question.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer. I am working with OpenEdge 11.6, i can't figure out how to change the above code to incorporate the web navigator inside a frame.

Comment: The above code runs Internet explorer as an external application. You need it embedded in your frame?

Comment: @MikeFechner Yes exactly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AppBuilder, choose "OCX" from the palette. Then drag the "Microsoft Web Browser" Active X Control on your frame.

To navigate to a certain web-page use:

```
chCtrlFrame:WebBrowser:Navigate ("http://www.progress.com").
```